# SSIS Execute SQL Task error Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "" failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have the following issue on SSIS.
I am trying to initiate destination tables using "Execute SQL Task" components.
These components fail to execute with the error:

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "The recovery of the COM class object for the item with CLSID {0EB5013B-538B-456B-AF1B-96DD1004026B} failed due to the following error: 80040153 Incorrect value for the registry (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040153) (REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE)).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

No matter what SQL statement I put in the component to execute. Even a simple SELECT * FROM  fails. Allways the same error. I have noticed reading the error text, that it cannot even get the query to be executed, since the place where the query text should be in the message is empty (...Executing the query "" failed...).

Can anybody give me a hint of what is wrong with this component?

I am using Visual studio Community 2019 version 16.8.3 and SQL server 2019 Developer edition.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like your SSDT / Visual Studio installation is corrupt. This is quite common. I suggest you try a repair or reinstall.

Comment: Have you installed the latest CU (Cumulative Update) for SQL Server 2019? REF: [Integration Services Project execution failure on Execute SQL task](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1085995/integration-services-project-execution-failure-on.html)

Comment: I have downloaded the SQL Server latest CU and all worked. Thanks